# Installing pgrouting on Ubuntu 16.04 fails

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting, ubuntu

I tried to install pgrouting on **Ubuntu 16.04** but I got following error message:

```
CREATE EXTENSION pgrouting;
```

> could not open extension control file "/opt/PostgreSQL/9.6/share/postgresql/extension/pgrouting.control": file or directory not found

I downloaded the EnterprisDB **Postgres(9.6)** Bundle, installed postgres ant then installed PostGis using the **stackbuilder**.
I was able to create the PostGis extension and the topology extension.
Some other extensions like pgrouting fail to install.

Does anyone know why intallation of some extensions fail?

I did the same on Win10 a few days ago an everything worked.

Comment: Don't use EnterpriseDb Postgre 9.6 Linux if you want pgRouting.  Use PostgreSQL Apt as dkastl noted in his answer.  The EDB windows stackbuilder is the only EDB version at this time that contains pgRouting because I package that one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because pgRouting can be installed as Ubuntu package from the PostgreSQL Apt repository, the easiest way is to add this repository and then run

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.6-pgrouting
```

How to add the PostgreSQL Apt repository is described here: https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/

I don't know what "stackbuilder" means for Ubuntu, because I only try installation via package manager, but in case you have installed another version of PostgreSQL, too, make sure that:

- you are using the PostgreSSQL 9.6 (and not the other version)
- you have installed pgRouting for PostgreSQL 9.6

Comment: Full instructions here to get PostGIS and pgRouting together from apt https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiPostGIS23UbuntuPGSQL96Apt .

Comment: Stackbuilder is installer for EDB's distributions and they have one for windows, mac, Linux - https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads#linux  (the PostGIS Bundle for windows I manage, so it's offerings are different from what you'd find on the Linux/Mac stackbuilder EDB.  It's a bit confusing I know.

Comment: The pgRouting workshop actually has an installation chapter, too. It uses PostgreSQL 9.3 in its example, but you can change this to 9.6 as well: http://workshop.pgrouting.org/2.1.0-dev/en/chapters/additional_installation.html

Comment: Used `sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.5-pgrouting`, worked perfectly!